# Graphing the sequence {$p_k$} = $\frac{c - a + dp_{k-1}}{b}$

Tags: graphics, coding-style, sequence, code-generation

Graphing the sequence {$p_k$} = $\frac{c - a + dp_{k-1}}{b}$

I need to know how to graph this function where it automatically plugs in the previous term for $p_{k-1}$, the coefficients are of my choosing lets just say $a=1$, $b=3$, $c=2$, $d=-1$,  these numbers are arbitrary. The whole point is that i want to find out what coefficients will make this oscillate.

Comment: A simple closed solution shows that it won't oscillate: `RSolve[p[n + 1] == c + d p[n], p[n], n]`.

Comment: Are you sure? You code return `p[n] -> 1 - (-1)^n + (-1)^(-1 + n) C[1]` it looks like oscillations

Comment: @molekyla777 Of course, it alternates. I think I was simply seeing the absence of a two-term recursion, so I immediately ruled out a real smooth oscillation. But even a geometric sequence can alternate, giving a rather trivial form of oscillation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach these recursive functions in a number of ways (as comments refer to or link to).

Using your arbitrary choice of values for $a,b,c,d$ and variable starting value I illustrate two approaches to motivate playing to achieve desired exploration.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_] := (c - a + d x)/b
rec[s_, n_] := NestList[f[1, 3, 2, -1, #] &, s, n];
fun[a_, b_, c_, d_, u_, 
  s_] := (p[n] /. 
     First@RSolve[p[n + 1] == (c - a + d p[n])/b, p[n], n] /. {C[1] ->
       s}) /. n -> u
Manipulate[Column[{
   ListPlot[rec[st, 10], Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True],
   DiscretePlot[fun[1, 3, 2, -1, u - 1, -st/3], {u, 1, 11, 1}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True]}],
 {{st, 0, "start"}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

Some of the code is just to adjust indices so plots would line up.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful , very advanced for me though. I'm playing around with it a bit but i cant seem to get it to plot anymore then 15 points, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i actually just figured out what to do, thank you very much for taking the time to help me i appreciate it.